# Listen for my color

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, knowledge

I've been away from the site for a while with work, kids, and going back to school; but since I have some down-time this evening I've decided to write a few riddles for the community. As always, I hope you enjoy it, and good luck!

---

> Known by all.
>
> Yet hidden from most.
>
> A noun of great wonder, a verb not verbose.
>
> Stand in a field.
>
> Look all around.
>
> The word isn't hidden, it waits to be found.
>
> I've told you.
>
> I'll tell you.
>
> Just sit here with me.
>
> Listen.
>
> Quit talking.
>
> Tranquility.

---

What color do you hear?

---

Please explain your answer.

Hint;

> Muffle your step, you’ll scare it away; stifled by noise, still you must stay.

Comment: Nice riddle! Boy, have I been busy with words myself... now to get back to riddling and puzzling... where is that riddle of mine that I need to answer? xD $(+1)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I thinked about a lot how good an answer

> gold

would be, but there are a lot of missing points.

*Known by all.*

*Yet hidden from most.*

> Everyone knows gold, but only the riches people can see it with their eyes.

*A noun of great wonder,*

> It is a great wonder itself, but if it were an adjective, it could refer to the Golden Gates Bridge, which is one of the 7 modern wonders of the World.

*a verb not verbose.*

> This is where I failed to find a connection. It could refer to William Golding, writer of The Lord of the Flies, but I hardly think anyone would found him *not* verbose.

*Stand in a field.*

*Look all around.*

*The word isn't hidden, it waits to be found.*

> It could refer to the gold pockets and the gold rush. Or who knows, maybe golden apple or corn marigold, which could be found on a field.

*I've told you.*

*I'll tell you.*

*Just sit here with me.*

*Listen.*

*Quit talking.*

*Tranquility.*

> And the main point why i think gould would be the best solution: you can listen to gold, because silence *is* golden.

Comment: You are so close to a complete answer! The focus word is actually in your answer and the color you've chosen is correct. How does the focus word relate to the passage instead of the color. This riddle was a red herring in itself to ensure you thought on the wrong side of the fence. :D

Answer (score 7):

The colour could be

> White

Known by all.
Yet hidden from most.

> White is a colour that everyone knows and learns throughout their life, but some don't see it (perhaps as snow, or referring to underground creatures that are white due to lack of sun)

A noun of great wonder,

> referring to "Great White Wonder", an album by Bob Dylan. Also white, the absence of all colour, could be regarded as quite a wonder.

a verb not verbose.

> To "White out" something is to remove words, causing it to be not as verbose

Stand in a field.
Look all around.
The word isn't hidden, it waits to be found.
I've told you.
I'll tell you.
Just sit here with me.
Listen.
Quit talking.
Tranquility.

> When you stop talking and listen to nothing, you may hear white noise, which many think of as relaxing

Comment: So close with that last line; wrong color, but so close!!!

Answer (score 5):

The answer could be

> Green.

Known by all.

Yet hidden from most.

> Green symbolizes nature. However, most people live in cities and they are unable to see natural beauty.

A noun of great wonder, a verb not verbose.

> ’Green’ is both a noun and a verb.

Stand in a field.

Look all around.

The word isn't hidden, it waits to be found.

> Fields are usually green…

Just sit here with me.

Listen.

Quit talking.

Tranquility.

> Green is a color that symbolizes peace and tranquility.

Comment: That was a great answer, so +1! I wouldn’t say you hear green though. :)

Comment: @PerpetualJ True. I thought the ‘listen’ was just in link with *quit talking* and *tranquility*.

Comment: Oh but it does, think of popular phrases related to color :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to say that the color is

> **Blue**

```
Known by all.

Yet hidden from most.
```

> The sky! Unfortunately, many people spend all their time inside these days.

```
A noun of great wonder, a verb not verbose.
```

> The first half - colloquial term for a blue whale is a "Big Blue". Those things are certainly a great wonder. Verb not verbose - maybe since blue is a homophone for "blew", which is a noise you make with your mouth without words.

```
Stand in a field.

Look all around.

The word isn't hidden, it waits to be found.
```

> Ya know. The sky.

```
I've told you.

I'll tell you.

Just sit here with me.

Listen.

Quit talking.

Tranquility.
```

> Blue is associated with tranquility and quietness (I can get you a source for that if you want.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it is

> Brown

Known by all.

> brown is a common color

Yet hidden from most.

> perhaps hidden beneath the grass?  or maybe this speaks of Brownian motion?

A noun of great wonder, a verb not verbose.

> Brown can be a color or even represent UPS as a noun.
>  as a verb, it can mean to make brown

Stand in a field.
Look all around.
The word isn't hidden, it waits to be found.

> Brown lies beneath the grass in a field

I've told you.
I'll tell you.
Just sit here with me.
Listen.
Quit talking.
Tranquility.

> Could this be brown noise?  a form of random noise some find relaxing.

Answer (score 3):

(inspired by Annosz's answer)
Is it

> The color of *gold* that is **Silence**

```
Known by all.
Yet hidden from most.
```

> It is

```
A noun of great wonder, a verb not verbose.
```

> noun and verb

```
Stand in a field.
Look all around.
The word isn't hidden, it waits to be found.
I've told you.
I'll tell you.
Just sit here with me.
Listen.
Quit talking.
Tranquility.
```

> Silence is waiting to be found by staying silent

Muffle your step, you’ll scare it away; stifled by noise, still you must stay.

> silence is disturbed by noise (step) and staying still bring silence

Answer (score 2):

I believe I hear the color:

> Blue

Known by all.

Yet hidden from most.

A noun of great wonder, a verb not verbose.

> This could all refer to the **sea**. Everyone knows of the sea, but many don't get to see it. The Sea is a great wonder, but to *see* is a simple verb, not very verbose.

Stand in a field.

Look all around.

The word isn't hidden, it waits to be found.

> If you stand in an open space, like a field, the sky is all around you. What color is the sky? Blue

I've told you.

I'll tell you.

Just sit here with me.

Listen.

Quit talking.

Tranquility.

> The sound of the ocean has a few intricacies. These lines I'm unsure of though.

As for the Hint:

> Muffle your step, you’ll scare it away; stifled by noise, still you must stay.

I believe this is:

> If you disturb still water too much, it will become white with foam. Such as whitewater rapids and such.